# How to share part of webpage on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, share

I have web page e.g.

> bricks.com/list

with navigation bar, side bar and dozen of small articles on the page. I should make it so users can share on facebook just one of that articles from the page without open another page to show single article.
Some people says it is impossible :) . Is it?

Comment: Create a unique URL for each article. And then share the unique URL.

Comment: You mean with id? Like someurl.com/list#someting?

Comment: Stuff after # never leaves the browser so that will not work.

Comment: Please, give me some directions.

Comment: Make it someurl.com/article.php?id=1 or someurl.com/article/1

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: Why this is downvoted?